# how to make new intents open after having intent

Tags: java, android

So far I have a button from my second activity that opens a new activity. As shown below..

---

```
public class FifthActivity extends Activity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, AmazonActivity.class);
            FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Now the thing is, I have multiple buttons in my `fifthActivity.java` that I need to make start a new Activity. Going from this code, From what part of the code do I need to put in my `FifthActivity.java` to make it so the other buttons open?

Comment: "From what part of the code do I need to put in my FifthActivity.java to make it so the other buttons open?" - can you make your question clear

Comment: what do you mean by from what part ?

Comment: I have other buttons that I need to be opened. I just need to know from which part of the code do I need to use to include the other buttons to open.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know, if I get your question. But I guess your `FifthActivity` contains some buttons and you want to start different activities with these buttons. (Am I right?)

Heres an short example:

```
public class FifthActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, Activity1.class);
            FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, Activity3.class);
            FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is really basic android programming. If you struggle with this you should probably do some android tutorials, before starting programming your own app.